# If I'm customizing chisel3's Queue Util, what should I do with genType?

Tags: chisel

I'm trying to customize `Queue` up a bit without forking chisel3 and building from source. I'm a bit confused on the correct way to take out the interal package use. What should I do with the ReadyValidIO `genType`?

```scala
private val genType = (DataMirror.internal.isSynthesizable(gen), chisel3.internal.Builder.currentModule) match {
  case (true, Some(module: Module))
      if !module.compileOptions.declaredTypeMustBeUnbound => chiselTypeOf(gen)
  case _ => gen
}
```

and the Queue `genType`?

```scala
  val genType = if (compileOptions.declaredTypeMustBeUnbound) {
    requireIsChiselType(gen)
    gen
  } else {
    if (DataMirror.internal.isSynthesizable(gen)) {
      chiselTypeOf(gen)
    } else {
      gen
    }
  }
```

If I know I'm only using this for synthesizable gen types, can I just pass in `chiselTypeOf(gen)` to `genType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use `gen`, ie. `val genType = gen` (or just use `gen` and don't have `genType`).

All of internal stuff is dealing with the fact that in Chisel 2 (which is still supported-ish via `import Chisel._` in the chisel3 codebase) did not distinguish between *hardware types* and *hardware values*. Thus, to help make `import Chisel._` work, there is some checking to see if we should clone the type (via `chiselTypeOf`), but this is not the recommended way to make your own API work.

When creating a `Queue`, it should always be done with a type so you could put in a `requireIsChiselType`, but you don't need to since things like `Input(_)` and `IO(_)` call that method internally.